# Retrieve image from Firebase Storage

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-storage

I am trying to pull an image from Firebase storage so i can then use the URL of the image to put into an Imageview. Most of the answers i find are to do with android studio, no answers for xamarin. This is the code i have so far:

```
storage = FirebaseStorage.Instance;
storageRef = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://......com");

StorageReference ImageFolder = storageRef.Child("Images");
StorageReference UserFolder = ImageFolder.Child(auth.CurrentUser.Email);
StorageReference UserImage = storageRef.Child("profile pic");
```

I can upload to firebase storage no problem, its the retrieving part that is the problem. In firebase storage i have folder Images/userEmail/profilePic.

Any links or documentation someone could point me in the direction of or any help would be great thanks.

Comment: does it work now ?

Comment: Hey Leo, yes i got it working, I will post the solution I found when I have time, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you could implement the `IOnSuccessListener` interface and get tht result int the `OnSuccess` method
like this:

let your activity implement `IOnSuccessListener` interface:

```
public class YourActivity: Activity, IOnSuccessListener, IOnFailureListener
 {
  ...
 }
```

use `Android.Gms.Tasks.Task` download the file and set into imageview in the `OnSuccess` call back:

```
StorageReference ImageFolder = storageRef.Child("Images");
StorageReference UserFolder = ImageFolder.Child(auth.CurrentUser.Email);
StorageReference UserImage = UserFolder.Child("profile pic");
StorageReference testRef = UserImage.Child("test.jpg");
Task downloadtask = testRef.GetBytes(1200 * 800);
downloadtask.AddOnSuccessListener(this);
downloadtask.AddOnFailureListener(this);

public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception e)
 {
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "storage", "Failed:" + e.ToString());
 }

public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
 {
    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "storage", "success!");
    if (downloadtask != null)
    {
        var data = downloadtask.Result.ToArray<byte>();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
        imageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        downloadtask = null;
    }
 }
```

there are several ways to do this
you could refer to the [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url)